# Revert the use of filter-branch in Git

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I used git filter-branch and screwed something up and accidentally rewrote sections of the history I didn't want to. I was trying to change one name and accidentally changed every single commit (instead of only ones with a specific name).

I know that 'git filter-branch' keeps a backup at refs/original, but I don't know how to revert the master branch to this old version. What's the git command to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the commit id you're trying to revert to, you can use

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard <commit id>
```

Comment: The commit id should be available in refs/original.

Comment: Reflog syntax was made for situations like this.

    git checkout master@{1}
    git branch -f master